# grep recursively to look for occurrence of a word in a particular file

Tags: search, grep

I know about

```
grep -rin 'text' /path/to/direcotry
```

But I dont want to look up in all the files . I just need to check for occurrence of 'text' in all files named wscript. How can that be done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

man grep:

```
   --include=GLOB
          Search  only  files whose base name matches GLOB (using wildcard
          matching as described under --exclude).
```

so try this:

```
grep -rin --include=wscript 'text' /path/to/files
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 grep -rin 'text' `find /path/to/directory -name wscript`
```

Comment: did'nt work man.

Comment: Note that the quotes around the find command are backquotes  not regular quotes.

Comment: The backticks are hard to read, I'd suggest using `$()` instead. I'd also recommend not to use command substitution for parsing find output, it'll likely break. A safer alternative would be to pipe it to `xargs` in a null-delimited format.

Comment: I rolled this back to my version. @slhck 's version is fine, but it's completely different, and belongs in its own answer.

Comment: Note that @Serge's answer is better than mine. I even upvotted it!

Comment: Sure, but it's nothing *completely* different, just the same command in a different version. I've just seen a lot of examples online that are "good enough" or work for a certain situation but are not portable. In you case, if you didn't have the restriction on `-name wscript`, and there was a file named `foo bar`, this would lead to two errors and the file not being searched.

Comment: I'll agree that my version is not the best way to do it. But I see your version as a very basic change, not a revision.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -rin 'your-text' /path/to/text/file/text-file.txt
```

It works only with text files, though.

Comment: That doesn't restrict the files by name.